# Number theoretical function applied in physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, fourier-transform, hamiltonian, partition-function

I have a series of number theoretic phenomena (mathematics) that I can describe exactly by the superpositions or linear combination of the below function (I know it is an inverse Fourier type). Does anybody knows from parallels in physics (quantum, particle, waves) where exactly this function is applied? Are there perhaps other notations in physics of this function. The question is very important for me trying to investigate this equation.

$$G(x)=\sum_{k=-j}^j \frac{2 \pi}{j}\,e^{(i\,2\pi\,(k-1)\,x / j)}$$

while $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and angular frequency:

$$\omega_j=\frac{2 \pi}{j}$$

PS: interestingly if $j\rightarrow \infty$ we get a ${\rm sinc}$ function that if squared then corresponding to pair-correlation function for the eigenvalues of a random Hermitian matrix a model of the energy levels in heavy nuclei.

Note: of course taking the first and second derivative of the function $\frac{2 \pi}{j}\,e^{(i\,2\pi\,(k-1)\,x / j)}$ we can construct easily the differential equation of a harmonic oscillator.

Comment: This reminds me of the outgoing sperical wave part when describing scattering processes by an infalling plane wave which turns into the transmitted part plus a spherical wave part. Not sure about it at present...

Comment: exciting. may you help me with a hint where I can learn more about this?

Comment: The sum is geometric series.
It is straightforward to work out that
$$G(x) = \frac{2\pi}{j}\csc\frac{\pi x}{j}\sin\frac{(2j+1)\pi x}{j}
e^{-i 2\pi x/j}.$$

Comment: yes the sum converges and this is why we can easily calculate the limit for $j$ vs. infinity.